# SQL Dynamically Split Values into new columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, cross-apply, charindex

Have a table that contains different IP values for objects separated by commas. Looking for way to split them dynamically into new columns. For example,

```
10.12.11.20, 192.168.1.3, 192.168.1.4
192.168.1.50,
```

Based on the results returned in the table would like to split them into the respected columns (IPAddress0, IPAddress1, etc) Would it be easier/better to split these values into new rows?

Update:

Attempted the following:

```
 substring(ip,1,charindex(',',ip.IP)-1) as Col1
,substring(ip,charindex(',',ip.IP)+1,len(ip.IP)) as Col2
```

This resulted in 1st IP and 2nd IP into new columns, but if the object has more IPs than that they show up in Col2

Comment: If you don't know the number of columns in the result set, this will be much more cumbersome than you probably expect.

Comment: @GordonLinoff what would you propose on how to approach it if objects can contain one or more values?

Comment: @Austin4778 What dbms are you using? Is it strictly required that you have a table with each ip as it's own column - what about a table with each ip as it's own row and you can wrangle it however you want when querying it.

Comment: @Error_2646 SQL Server. new rows would be fine as well. Just need to split the addresses by the comma delimiter

Comment: @Austin4778 This should do the trick for you then https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493510/turning-a-comma-separated-string-into-individual-rows

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Turning a Comma Separated string into individual rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493510/turning-a-comma-separated-string-into-individual-rows)

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss that's the same article that Error_2646 provided

Answer (score 0):

If you have SQL 2016 or later and rows are OK for you as well, you can use STRING_SPLIT as below.

```
SELECT VALUE FROM STRING_SPLIT ( '10.12.11.20,192.168.1.3,192.168.1.4' , ',' )
```